# how I can do a replacement to an element in specific index without replace all the same elements in other index as a string in java

Tags: java, string

how I can  do a replacement to an element in specific index without replace all the same elements in other index as a string in java , like input a string "22" ,and you should make the last char be 0 , so if I did the built-in method , string.replace(oldchar,newchar) ,it'll replace the first 2 too , because I replaced a char to another , not index to another one ,so what the solution in java  ?!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace the last occurrence of a string in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325800/replace-the-last-occurrence-of-a-string-in-another-string)

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex negative lookahead:

```
str = str.replaceAll("2(?!.*2)", "0");
```

Regex breakdown:

- `2` a literal "2"
- `(?!.*2)` a negative lookahead for a "2", which in English means "a 2 does not exist after this point in the input"